# Does Newton's third law of motion fail anywhere?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws

Does Newton's third law of motion fail anywhere, including particle physics and other advanced topics?

Answer (score 11):

In electromagnetic theory, Newton's 3rd law is not obeyed, because the momentum of  matter may not be conserved - there is electromagnetic momentum too. The law of local conservation of total momentum then replaces the 3rd law.